# Ubuntu Touch for Nexus 7 2012

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I know **Ubuntu Touch** for **Nexus 7 (2012)** has been deprecated. But there must be an option for installing it on my tablet anyway, the thing is all the tutorials I find are old, and refer to the time when the official version was available.

Is there any community developing an updated version for this tablet? Or is there any way of installing the latest version (even if it is now deprecated)?